# How to get the path of a file inside a project to read it with OpenCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a CSV file inside a folder that's inside the source folder but I can't get to it.

I got it to work with what I've found on internet:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/csv/recetas.csv");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(fileReader, ',', '"', 1);
```

but it only works when I run it in the IDE. When I build the jar and try to run it, the FileReader can't find the file, it doesn't throw error for URL or File.

Here is my [project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LjRp.png) so you can understand me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/csv/recetas.csv");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
CSVReader(reader, ',', '"', 1);
```

*Resources* are class path "files" possibly packed in a jar. They are **not** `File`, and are read-only.

Also for compatibility, give the charset explicitly.

Comment: What should I do to write on the file? I tried with OutputStream but isn't working, I might done it wrong

Comment: You can use the resource file as "template" only, to create an almoste empty CSV file with column names. Keep the actual file maybe in `System.getProperty("user.hjome") + "/myapp/recetas.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

The `getClass().getResource()` uses the class loader to load the resource. This means that your csv file will not be visible unless it is in the `classpath`.

Looking at your code and your problem again, `getClass().getResource()` seems redundant to me as the constructor of `File(...)` accepts a file path depicted as String.

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Quote:

> File(String pathname) Creates a new File instance by converting the
>   given pathname string into an abstract pathname.

To make your program more versatile I would recommend you to avoid hardcoding the file path as the csv file can be anywhere within the file system and it may not always be called `recetas.csv`.

What people typically would do is to make the `java` program accept an option like `--csv`. Then let the user specify the filepath and your code will just be `new File(theSpecifiedPath)`.